Add a value on their SESSION_CONTEXT for all sys.dm_exec_sessions
When consulting sys.dm_exec_sessions is it possible to attach them their session_context?
I have a backend with a pool of 100 connections. When a connection is assigned to a new incoming request I store the user making that request to the connection's session_context.
exec sp_set_session_context @Key = N'User', @Value = @user_id

Now when I face a deadlock I would like to identify the users involved getting their session_context's 'User' value of each sys.dm_exec_sessions.
Is it possible? Thank you.

Not quite sure I understand the request but in all versions since SQL Server 2005, you should be using new catalog views like sys.dm_exec_sessions, and sys.dm_exec_connections. sysprocesses has been deprecated for nearly two decades, and there's a big note in the documentation warning you not to use it: https://i.sstatic.net/xVAIYGNi.png

@AaronBertrand I've updated the question to target dm_exec_sesions. Thank you.

The wording in the question and the title conflict for me, but if I understand the request, you want to run a command that will add a value to the SESSION_CONTEXT of a bunch of sessions? I don't think this is possible. The procedure affects each session individually, and they own their own session context (like they own their own #temp tables). You could do this in a logon trigger for newly established sessions, but I suspect you're better off pursuing it from the application side - store the new value somewhere, and have the app always check that source, and set it on the next request.

@AaronBertrand thank you, I thought that the session_contexts could be stored on some system table, so I would be able to query the session_context of certain spid to identify the user that issued a conflicting command.

Don't think you can access this value for other users

Thansk @siggemannen then I would store that information on a custom table instead of session_context.

"I have a backend with a pool of 100 connections." IMO this is a complete design fallacy. You don't need to implement your own connection pooling, the driver should do this automatically.

@Charlieface I haven't implemented a full pool management myself, I've requested a pool to my framework. I assume that the framework does it optimally using the driver resources in the best way.

While it's normally recommended to use the newer sp_set_session_context, it's impossible to get that information from a different connection, and it's not available in XEvents or in any of the DMVs.
Instead you can use the older CONTEXT_INFO. Do note that it only allows a maximum of 128 bytes, and you may want to check that no-one else is using it, as there are no keys.
DECLARE @userBinary varbinary(128) = CAST(@user_id AS varbinary(128));
SET CONTEXT_INFO @userBinary;

You can use SELECT CONTEXT_INFO(); to view it, or get it from the context_info column in both dm_exec_sessions and dm_exec_requests. It's also available in XEvent sessions, under the context_info field.

Thank you. I only need to share an integer for session, so this is perfect for me.

While ChatGPT might suggest it's possible, no, you can't change someone else's SESSION_CONTEXT. You can't even see it. This is by design - a session's context is private to that session, just like #temp tables.
The application could (on user login, maybe?) store information along with the session_id in a session-keyed table, e.g.
CREATE TABLE dbo.SessionContext
(
  session_id int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT @@SPID,
  user_info  nvarchar(64)
);

Then on login, the app can send:
DELETE dbo.SessionContext WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
INSERT dbo.SessionContext(user_info) VALUES(N'username');

It could also set SESSION_CONTEXT(), but it doesn't sound like that will be helpful in your use case because only they could see it. However, I have to wonder how often you'll react to a deadlock fast enough that the sessions are still active. It might be that you need a running log, e.g.:
CREATE TABLE dbo.SessionContext
(
  session_id      int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT @@SPID,
  user_info       nvarchar(64),
  session_started datetime2 NOT NULL DEFAULT sysutcdatetime()
);

Then just insert on login:
INSERT dbo.SessionContext(user_info) VALUES(N'username');

Now when you know the time of the deadlock, you can figure out the users involved by saying:
DECLARE @spid1 int = 77, 
        @spid2 int = 99,
        @deadlocktime datetime2 = 'some date/time';

SELECT TOP (1) user_info 
  FROM dbo.SessionContext
 WHERE session_id = @spid1
   AND session_started < @deadlocktime
 ORDER BY session_started DESC;

SELECT TOP (1) user_info 
  FROM dbo.SessionContext
 WHERE session_id = @spid2
   AND session_started < @deadlocktime
 ORDER BY session_started DESC;

